# How to slide a drawer 80% of a screen from left to right

Tags: android, android-layout, slider, navigation-drawer, android-layout-weight

I don't want to set a fixed width because the application will run in different devices which containing different **screen size**. I am so new to android please help me to set a %of screen like **Weight** .

Here you can see i set a width size "260dp" so that i faced a problem in Nexus7 so please help me to fix this problem

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listMenu"
android:layout_width="260dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_image"
android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/servicelayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:onClick="serviceclose" >
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/serviceicon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/find_services_icon"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="Find Services"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
       <View
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="1dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />
       <LinearLayout 
              android:id="@+id/reviewlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/reviewicon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/reviews_icon"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="Reviews"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

          <View
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="1dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />
             <LinearLayout 
             android:id="@+id/myprofilelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/availabilityicon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/booked_services_icon"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="Booked Services"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
               android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="1dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use `Relative Layout` instead of `Linear Layout`

Comment: you can target more device with that

Comment: @mohit How to set The WIDTH after using Relative layout. In relative layout there is no choice of set Weight in it

Comment: @Nouman i dont want to fix width that's why i am posting this question please help me.

Comment: is this your side drawer..

Comment: yes it is my slide drawer layout

Answer (score 0):

Try this. By creating v4 drawer layout , you don't need to manage it's width . System will automatically do it. As you are you..I recommend you to see [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) , [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android) , [this](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2014/02/android-navigation-drawer-example.html) and [this](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/) tutorial for complete implementation of drawer.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: It is not a listview Nouman ,it is totally a linear layout which i include in another layout.

Comment: it's just an example.. remove the list view . See those tutorials for batter understanding..

Comment: you can also do it by code .. In your drawer fragment 
mDrawerView.getLayoutParams().width = ScreenUtil
      .getPercentageWidth(getResources().getDisplayMetrics(),
        80);

Comment: public static int getPercentageWidth(DisplayMetrics displaymetrics,
   int percent) {
  int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
  int temp = percent * width;
  int calculatedPercentAge = (int) ((float) temp / 100);
  return calculatedPercentAge;
 }

Comment: this is a method I used which was in ScreenUtil class.Copy it and use it directly.. And change your width in layout to match parrent

Comment: Thank you Nouman but its just convert my whole screen to 80% i only want slide drawer to move 80%

Comment: it is converting my sliding drawer to 80% ..
Use it right after your view inflator..

Comment: i just use a library slide.jar and the class is Simple Slide Drawer class